# How to access nested modules (submodules) in Go?

Tags: go, go-modules

Go version: 1.12.9

Here is the structure of a simple demo project:

[image]

So we have a module **domain**, which contains two modules: **activity** and **person**.

I would like to use domain with all nested modules in the main file => *modules.go*.

I know how to import *domain* in the main *go.mod*:

```
module modules

go 1.12

replace modules/domain v0.0.0 => ./domain

require modules/domain v0.0.0
```

So after that can use code from *domain/domain.go*, but I **cannot access** code from *activity* and *person* modules.

Yes, I could manually import nested modules, for example:
(main go.mod):

```
module modules

go 1.12

replace modules/domain v0.0.0 => ./domain

replace modules/domain/activity v0.0.0 => ./domain/activity

require (
    modules/domain v0.0.0
    modules/domain/activity v0.0.0
)
```

but I don't want to manually import all submodules.

How to configure modules to import **domain** with all submodules?

Comment: You can't. That's not how modules work. But in your case these probably shouldn't be separate modules in the first place, just separate packages in the same module.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Yes, I could manually import nested modules [...]
> but I don't want to manually import all submodules.
> How to configure modules to import domain with all submodules ?

You simply cannot do this.

Some background:

- There is no real notion of "sub"-module, all modules are equal.
- Same for packages: all(*) packages are equal. If you want to use a package you must import it.
- The layout in the filesystem does not imply any kind of technical relation between packages (e.g. net/http/cookiejar is as much related to net/http as it is related crypto/md5: not at all).
- Being part of a module doesn't mean much: Modules are just sets of packages versioned together and doesn't add any additional relation between these packages.

The rule is dead simple: If you want to import a package you have to import it.

The fact that there are no magical wildcard imports might seem annoying (see below) but prevents unintended imports: Adding a package doesn't magically import it (and execute its init functions!).

In real live having to import all packages is not that annoying because "normal" Go code doesn't use tiny packages. This is a common mistake for someone indoctrinated by Java/C#/PHP/Node "project architectures" with lots of folders and tiny classes: Don't do that in Go. It is not helping. It often even  leads to circular import and hurts.

Same for modules. A Go module is probably not what you think it is. A module is a *set* of packages **versioned** **together**. I doubt there is a reason to provide different versions for package person and package domain at the  same time. (It is *allowed* to  have several modules in one repository/project, but having more than one is a *very* rare case, yours clearly isn't).

Best advice (in order of relevance):

- Stop making every package its own module.
- Stop making tiny packages.
- Stop trying to mimick a source code layout ("architecture") you might be used from other languages.

(*) internal and vendored packages are an exception which does not apply to your problem.

Comment: "How to Write Go Code" only documents the flawed approach of writing Go code in GOPATH, it has not been updated to document Go Modules.

Comment: Actually as of today (1/19/20) they **FINALLY** updated "How To Write Go Code" actually using the module system. https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: @slezica You are right, I was annoyed and a bit insulted. This is a clear XY problem with the wanted solution being utterly dangerous. I tried to explain a bit  more.

Comment: @Volker Fantastic rewrite :) thank you! It will be appreciated by future readers, I'm sure.

Comment: A reasonable use-case for nested modules is to isolate the dependencies of 
a package that is imported by other modules.  For example, Kubernetes operators are routinely written in go, and consist of a set of type definitions in `pkg/apis`, and controller logic elsewhere.  Applications or tools that use these types needn't be bothered with the controller dependencies, so isolating the dependencies of `pkg/apis` makes sense.

Comment: Here is another official documents about proper code organization in a repository: https://go.dev/doc/modules/managing-source

Answer (score 2):

go 1.18 has the support for the new `multi-workspace` feature by `go.work` files.
for more info, check [golang workspace proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/45713-workspace.md)

Answer (score 0):

### I faced a similar situation with *Go 1.20*. Here is How I solved it.

#### Package

I have used a repository as package in my Go project. This repository is uses a sub-module.

Here is the .gitmodules file inside my repository **my-repository/services**:

[image]

#### Change

> What I was missing: 
> After the introduction of Workspace, submodules were treated differently. So now I need to create a **go.work** file. Needed to be placed at same level as go.mod.

*go.work*

```
go 1.20

use ./validator/validate
```

#### Usage

Now I want to use this package in my main repo. Imported it as,

[image]

This solved my issue. You can find the documentation at: [Setting up your workspace](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md)